# What is a good way to connect an analog soundboard to a computer?

Tags: sound-design, console

I have an [EPM 8](https://adn.harmanpro.com/product_attachments/product_attachments/1985_1422315863/EPM8-Top_original.jpg) mixer by Soundcraft. How could I connect the mixed signal in a stereo format? Is there any best way to minimize latency? Is firewire good to use? I have a Firewire input on my computer. I want to run it through Audacity. Is FireWire slower than USB 3.0? Is there a "best" way to configure it?

Thanks in advance, Charlie

Comment: The difference in latency between firewire & USB is minimal; your computer itself will be the limiting factor, how small a buffer it can run without the signal breaking up.

Comment: Is USB 3.0 better?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The connection latency will be nothing like your computer's latency.

Comment: I want to keep it stereo, and how do I do that with a USB audio interface? Could I use a optical S/PDIF port to get the sound in my computer?

Comment: You could use S/PDIF... but as the EPM8 doesn't appear to use it [ref https://www.soundcraft.com/en/products/epm8 ], what would that gain you except for yet another hardware purchase? [if not two... idk many PCs that have S/PDIF input as standard]. I think you're getting caught up in the Y part of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: My pc has one S/PDIF input. Would it be better to use USB 3.0?

Comment: It still doesn't really matter. Pretty much any audio interface available at a music retailer will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "record outputs" on your mixer which are RCA left and right (stereo) outputs, and connect them to a USB interface. Something like [this interface](https://media.sweetwater.com/api/i/q-82__ha-70a772702affb2c8__hmac-feaa61dff389216af4a95075f4cb6edf751aad1a/images/items/750/UCA202-large.jpg) would be all you need.

The difference between firewire and usb isn't really about speed as much as it is about load, and you don't really start to see the benefits of firewire unless you are working with a lot of inputs and outputs. USB will be fine for your needs since you're only recording two channels.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this device only has analog outputs. Have you thought about connecting it to your ***Line In*** connector on your internal sound card? You may also want to use some sort of recording and mastering software (as you mentioned Audacity) such as Sony's Sound Forge?